# Alternative of Stata's foreach command in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stata

I am a new user of R and am used to using Stata software.

I used to loop through multiple variables by `foreach` command in Stata. So, for example, I can convert multiple numerical variables to factor ones.

In Stata, first, define the label:

`label define NoYes 0 "No" 1 "Yes"`

Then, apply the loop command:

```
foreach x in var1 var2 var3 {
    label values `x' NoYes
}
```

I am figuring out how I can do so in R; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to be specific without a reproducible example, but perhaps you are looking for lapply, as in e.g. `my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, as.factor)`, or perhaps `my_data[] <- lapply(my_data, factor, levels = 0:1, labels = c('No', 'Yes'))`.

Comment: Corrected the main code example.

Comment: Thank you all; let me explain more.
I have a dataset in Excel format. It has more than 50 variables, all numerical but two variables. I imported it to R as an Excel file:
`library(readxl)`
`passem <- read_excel("Library/PASSEM.xlsx")`

`passem$cci_pulmo <- factor(passem$cci_pulmo, levels = 0:1, labels = c('No', 'Yes'), ordered = TRUE)`
Instead of changing only one variable at once, I want to change multiple variables with looping.

Comment: Not the question but the example of a Stata loop is overkill as `label val x1 x2 x3 NoYes` would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R we can use `lapply`.

```
dat[c(1, 3)] <- lapply(dat[c(1, 3)], factor, levels=0:1, labels=c('No', 'Yes'))
dat
#    X1 X2  X3 X4 X5
# 1  No  1  No  1  0
# 2  No  1 Yes  1  1
# 3  No  0  No  0  0
# 4  No  1  No  0  0
# 5 Yes  0 Yes  0  0
# 6 Yes  1 Yes  0  0
```

To avoid confusion, I generally recommend not using too many fancy packages while you're new to R.

The literal translation could look like this (reload `dat` before trying):

```
for (x in c('X1', 'X3')) {
  dat[[x]] <- factor(dat[[x]], levels=0:1, labels=c('No', 'Yes'))
}
dat
#    X1 X2  X3 X4 X5
# 1  No  1  No  1  0
# 2  No  1 Yes  1  1
# 3  No  0  No  0  0
# 4  No  1  No  0  0
# 5 Yes  0 Yes  0  0
# 6 Yes  1 Yes  0  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X2 = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), X4 = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X5 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0), 
         var2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
         var3 = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
```

There may be several alternatives, and `across` of `dplyr` is one of them.

```
new_df <- df %>% mutate(across(var1:var3, ~ factor(.x, levels = c(0, 1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))))

new_df
  var1 var2 var3
1  Yes   No   No
2  Yes   No  Yes
3   No  Yes   No
4   No  Yes  Yes
```

You do not really need `levels = c(0, 1)` here, but I would always do it in real data just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you! but it does not change the variable in the environment if I type `table(var1)` ; it give output with 0 and 1

Comment: I see. I have edited my answer and assigned a new name to the changed data frame, just check the differences between `df` and  `new_df`.  The changed values are in the data frame: `table(new_df$var1)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works very well now